# Odoo - group records by date and print them with Python

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I need to make a report where each record has unique date. But my data has multiple records on the same date.

So I have to find  way to aggregate the records and sum one of the columns (`unit_amount` in this case) if date is the same. Like this:

[image]

Rest of the fields in the records can be taken for example from the first record with that particular date. Or even left empty if it will be much easier.

Currently I have such python code:

```py
class HrTimesheetKartyReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty'

    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, data=None):
        hr_analytic_timesheet = self.env['hr.analytic.timesheet']
        if data and 'wizard_id' in data:
            wizard = self.env['hr.timesheet.karty.wizard'].browse(
                data['wizard_id'])
            records = hr_analytic_timesheet.search([('user_id', '=', wizard.user_id.id),
                                                    ('date', '>=', wizard.date_from),
                                                    ('date', '<=', wizard.date_to)])                                                    
        else:
            records = hr_analytic_timesheet.browse(self._ids)

        # here sum the record.unit_amount if date is the same (group by date)

        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name(
            'hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty')
        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': self._ids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': records,
        }
        return report_obj.render('hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty', docargs)
```

I'm selecting records to be printed inside variable `records` and I need to group them before printing.

I'm using Odoo8.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Gumaa

You can use the def `read_group` method to filter the data with your `domain` and the `field` which you want to filter with the group by. For Example:

```
reached_goals = self.pool.get('gamification.goal').read_group(cr, uid, [
                ('challenge_id', '=', challenge.id),
                ('end_date', '=', end_date),
                ('state', '=', 'reached')
            ], fields=['user_id'], groupby=['user_id'], context=context)
```

Thanks

Comment: I went with your suggestion and I wrote this: `records = hr_analytic_timesheet.read_group([('user_id', '=', wizard.user_id.id),
                                                    ('date', '>=', wizard.date_from),
                                                    ('date', '<=', wizard.date_to)],
                                                    ['user_id','date','unit_amount'],
                                                    ['date'])`
But now I'm getting empty report with no data.

Comment: **read_group:** return: list of dictionaries(one dictionary for each record) containing:                                                                -  **the values of fields** grouped by the fields in ``groupby`` argument                         - **__domain**: list of tuples specifying the search criteria                                          -**__context**: dictionary with an argument like ``groupby``                                   *You can use `date:day` in `groupby`*

Comment: I already tried `date:day` and it does not work. How do I print this list? Do I need to convert it to a different data type?

Comment: The result depend on the date ranges? Can give an example that did not work for the sample you give above.

Comment: @Gumaa, Make Sure your provided domain with satisfied your record condition than, and then you will get the output.

Comment: @DipenShah I think domain is fine because it is exactly the same as in `search()` I used previously and it was working. Are you sure I can just use the output of `read_group()` the same way like `search()`? I mean if it returns list of dictionaries rather than model records can I use it directly in the report? I get errors like this: `QWebException: "'dict' object has no attribute '_fields'" while evaluating`

Comment: Yes, only with the read_group you can filter the record by the added the filed on 
group_by. but I preferred you can use with cr, uid like the same on read_group.

Comment: As I understand version with `cr` and `uid` is from old odoo api and I'm using new one. So I used it without it.

Comment: @Kenly I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you want to see exactly?

Comment: For now only this approach is kinda working for me:
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-groups-the-same-value-report-in-qweb-odoo-137717

Comment: @Gumaa What are the dates you choose in the wizard?

Comment: @Kenly like from `01-04-2019` to `30-04-2019`. I'm not sure why is that important. I choose the same dates as with `search` and back then I got all the records from that period. But I think I will simply change my concept and go with a solution from that link above. Thanks for your help one again.

Comment: @Gumaa My remark was about choosing a `01-05-20` as `date_from`, `04-05-20` as `date_to` and `Test User` as user. Use `read_group` like following  `read_group([('user_id', '=', wizard.employee_id.user_id.id), ('date', '>=', wizard.date_from), ('date', '<=', wizard.date_to)], fields=['user_id', 'date', 'unit_amount'], groupby=['date:day'])`. Since it is working I wish you good luck.